# Require help installing a .jar file. (14.04)

Tags: 14.04, java, jar

I need help installing a .jar file, http://chunky.llbit.se/download.html, which is causing problems for me. I have Openjdk 7 and 6 and I got 8 from another, non official place. When I double click the .jar file, it doesn't open (I have the permission for allowing it to execute enabled). 
Running it through the terminal via java -jar gives this:

```
~/Downloads$ java -jar chunky-1.4.3.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/stage/Stage
    at se.llbit.chunky.launcher.ChunkyLauncher.firstTimeSetup(ChunkyLauncher.java:276)
    at se.llbit.chunky.launcher.ChunkyLauncher.main(ChunkyLauncher.java:194)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/stage/Stage
    ... 2 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.stage.Stage
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say where you got Java 8 and whether or not you installed it, or what version it is.

From the Chunky install web page at http://chunky.llbit.se/install.html:

---

*Before installing Chunky you will need Java 8 update 40 or later. You can download Java here.*

*On Ubuntu, and some other Linux distributions, you may have to install a JavaFX library to be able to run Chunky. On Ubuntu 16.04, just have to install the package openjfx.*

---

Which means that you need to at least install **default-jre** (OpenJDK 8) and **openjfx**.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jre openjfx
```

If that doesn't allow Chunky to run without error, you'll need to install the `Oracle Java 8` found at https://java.com/en/ or via ppa:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Comment: Sorry for not giving that much info, but you've solved my issue. Thank you! The first solution didn't seem to work, but the second PPA got it working for me.

Comment: @RandomHuman thanks for the update! Glad it's working!